# Two way relationship in SQL with 2 tables and no duplicates

Tags: sql, relational-database

Assuming you have 2 tables: `user` and `friends` - you want to join all friends to the user you query.

The obvious answer is:

```
SELECT friend.uid
FROM `user`
JOIN friends ON user.uid = friends.user
JOIN user AS friend ON friends.friend = friend.uid
WHERE user.uid = $user_id
```

This works fine but it's a one-way relationship. To make this work I'd have to add 2 rows for every relationship.

On the other hand, this works both ways:

```
SELECT friend.uid
FROM `user` 
JOIN friends ON user.uid IN(friends.col1, friends.col2)
JOIN user AS friend ON
  friend.uid IN(friends.col1, friends.col2)
WHERE user.uid = $user_id AND friend.uid != user.uid
```

But this is makes use of multiple `IN()`s is not very clean and probably comes with a big performance hit.

Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Can you please show table schema and sample data inputs and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply use `UNION ALL` and skip the join entirely, something like;

```
SELECT friends.col1 friend_uid FROM friends WHERE friends.col2 = $user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT friends.col2            FROM friends WHERE friends.col1 = $user_id
```

Comment: @JV That would really depend on the rdbms, but `UNION ALL` is a fairly simple operation as compared to `UNION`.

Comment: Ah I see. I imagine performance scales strangely given a large set of tables, but I don't have a large set of tables in the first place. What if I want additional data about the friends from the user table, how would that affect performance?